# How do I add Wes Anderson Colors to my GGPlot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use the "GrandBudapest1" palette from the wesanderson package.

I'm working on a graph that has 20 discrete values, but the palette only has 9 colors.

The docs say that I can create more colors with this code:

```
pal <- wes_palette(21, name = "GrandBudapest1", type = "continuous")
```

I'd like to apply that palette to my ggplot chart. I've tried a few things, but they haven't worked.

```
# organize the data
tdf_winners <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-04-07/tdf_winners.csv')

wins.by.winner_name <-
  tdf_winners %>% 
  count(winner_name) %>% 
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  mutate(total_wins = n) %>% 
  select(-n)

tdf_winners <-
  tdf_winners %>% 
  filter(start_date > ymd("1913-01-01")) %>%
  left_join(wins.by.winner_name, by = "winner_name") %>% 
    mutate(winner_name_lbl = ifelse(total_wins == 1, "One Time Winner",
                                  winner_name))

# create the graphic

gg <-
  tdf_winners %>% 
  ggplot(aes(edition, time_overall, fill = winner_name_lbl)) +
  geom_col()

gg + 
  scale_fill_paletteer_d("wesanderson::GrandBudapest1")
```

I also tried `gg + scale_fill_paletteer_d(pal)`

How can I apply my interpolated color palette to my ggplot chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of points. The palate has 4 values, not 9, and `winner_name_lbl` has 21 levels.

Regardless, we can use just need to use `scale_fill_manual`.

```
library(wesanderson)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tdf_winners, aes(x = edition, y = time_overall, fill = winner_name_lbl)) + geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(21, name = "GrandBudapest1", type = "continuous"), name = "") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I was under the impression that scale_fill_manual only worked with hexes. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, it does only work with hexes. But `wes_palatte` returns an object of class `palatte` which has a special `print` method that plots the colors. That object actually contains all the hexes. Try `str(wes_palette(21, name = "GrandBudapest1", type = "continuous"))` to see.